# Apache server home directory works only without www in the url

Tags: server, apache2

I've got a problem that arose when fiddling with subdomains and the directory locations of the web sever.

My website `steppinghat.com` loads perfectly fine, but if you try and load `www.steppinghat.com` you get a 403 forbidden error. I tried playing around with my config file to add a www as a 'subdomain' to direct it to the proper location (`/var/www/html`) but it doesn't seem to work.

I know I've changed a lot here, I'm not using the default directories and in the process of tinkering around trying to figure out how things work I really messed up here. Rather than just reverting the config file back to a backup I have, I want to learn and find out what went wrong.

My configuration file is here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13224284/

and my directory structure is like so (in a real basic layout):

```
potato:/var/www$ ls
html  plex  status  test
```

---

Adding to this, is this the proper way I should be handling subdomains? Should I be doing something different with my directory structure or the way I've made the entries in the config file? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I know where the 'forbidden' directory is that it is pointing to when you load with the www. It's trying to load what's inside `/var/www`

Comment: On line 239, if you remove the "www." And only leave it in the alias, what happens?

Comment: @allejo Same thing

Comment: Why are you duplicating Directory sections from 223-234? Are they necessary?

Comment: @allejo that was me just toying around with some things. They didn't make a difference and I've already removed it in my copy of the config

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the file permissions might be off. you'll want to chmod every file you want visible so that others can view them `chmod o+r <file name>` for each file. you can probably write a script for this if you have many many files.

Comment: That's not the problem. I figured that when you load with the www it points to `/var/www` instead of `/var/www/html` where it should be (and where it does if you enter the url without the `www.` suffix)

Comment: To add to what you suggested, the directory `/var/www` and everything inside it has the permissions `drwxr-xr-x` and the owner and group is owned by root

Comment: try making your document roots `/var/www/html/`

Comment: They are...aren't they?

Comment: with one last `/` on the end.

Comment: Didn't help. That was default anyway. Plus it loads with that as the document root for the subdomains